# Farkas' lemma applied to the system $Ax = \mathbf{1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Given $A\succ 0$ with $A_{ii}=1$ for all $i$, I want to determine necessary and/or sufficient conditions on $A$ such that
$$
Ax = \mathbf{1},\quad x\geq 0\quad\quad\quad(1)
$$
has a solution, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of all ones. By Farkas' lemma, the system above is feasible if the implication
$$
Ay \geq 0 \implies \mathbf{1}^\top y \geq 0\quad\quad\quad(2)
$$
holds for $A$.

The $2\times 2$ case is straightforward ((2) always holds, so a solution to (1) always exists), but is this true in general or for a specific class of $A$?

Comment: Is the direct sum of the 2x2 solution with an identity matrix not a solution?

Comment: Not sure I follow. For the 2x2 case, any PD $A$ with unit diagonal must have off-diagonal elements $|a| < 1$. Then, summing  the $Ay\geq 0$ constraints gives $(1+a)(y_1+y_2)\geq 0$, which implies $y_1+y_2 \geq 0$.